# How to handle Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') error?

Tags: javascript

How to handle Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0'). I want to trigger this in ajax success of select onchange.

```
    var date_sched = [];
    const output = {
        [date_sched[0].user_id]: date_sched[0].dates,
    };

    //var doctor_dates;
    $("#schedDay").on("show.datetimepicker update.datetimepicker",
        function() {
            highlight();
        });

    function highlight() {
        // var dateToHilight = text;
        var dateToHilight = output;
        var array = $("#schedDay").find(".day").toArray();

        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            var date = array[i].getAttribute("data-day");

            if (dateToHilight[doctor_dates].indexOf(date) > -1) {
                array[i].classList.add('highlighted');
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: date_sched is undefined

Comment: its a global variable, I set value of date_sched in ajax success

Comment: You try retrieve dates from first element of empty array (3rd line). This is a reason. I believe that output should be filled on ajax success, not earlier.

Comment: You could wrap your code in `if (date_sched.length) {` to make sure it actually has entries before trying to do stuff with them.